# fetched data disappears after page reload using vue state

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Am fetching data from an api
this is the action in store

```
fetchVisits({commit}) {
            axios.get('/api/visits')
                .then(res => {
                    commit('FETCH_VISITS', res.data)

                }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        },
    }
```

mutation

```
FETCH_VISITS(state, visits) {
            return state.visits = visits
        },
```

state

```
state: {
     visits:[]
    },
```

getter

```
getters: {
        visits: state => {
            return state.visits
        }

    },
```

dispatched action

```
created() {
            this.$store.dispatch('fetchVisits')
        },
```

But when i refresh the page the data to be displayed disappears

Comment: The store does not persist the data client side.If your intention is to persist client side data, you need a way to store it on the client. [the vuex-persist plugin](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist) accomplishes just that.

Answer (score 0):

Actions are triggered with the store.dispatch method. Now in your case you might missed to dispatch  the fetchVisit action or possible also, you dispatched that action in your other component which is not your main component. That's why when you hit reload the dispatch method was not invoke. To solve that .

You have to dispatch the  fetchVisit action in your main component to invoke it every time you reload the page. Or, you dispatch again that action to the component itself which you said the state is empty.  This is how you dispatch

this.store.dispatch('fetchVisits')

Comment: How could you say that state is empty ?

Comment: i dont know why its empty

Comment: Then where you dispatched the action ? On the same component where you reload the page ?

Comment: How do you check if state is empty ? Show it